# Text proccessing via Mysql Query

Tags: php, database, arrays, string, performance

I have lot's of URL that must be saved in DB for searching and updating , which solution is better for performance :

1-store url as string in a table that contain one column  , and in later get string from db and explode them to an array and use `array_search` function to find a URL :

stored url : `http://site1.com|http://site2.com|....`

search routine :

```
$is_unique= array_search("$url" ,explode($row['url'] , "|"));
```

2-insert one row per each URL in db table and use query for search and update.

Comment: I'd use a new row for each, its cleaner to read and less code required to output.

Comment: i prefer it too but why text processing not ?

Comment: What kind of search queries will you do? But generally you should go for 1 record per url.

Comment: somthing like `SELECT * FROM ignore_list` where url = $url`

Comment: some bug coming to my routines , array_search can not find an exisiting url in array 1 :-? , i think you are right

Answer (score 1):

Let MySQL handle searching. MySQL can make use of indexes, array_search cannot. Just be sure to declare an index on your url column. You can create an index with the following SQL statement:

```
CREATE INDEX url_index ON your_table_name (url);
```

If you bulk update your urls, you can wrap your updates in a transaction, which makes it faster, because the index will be re-generated on commit, not on every single update statement.

```
START TRANSACTION;
[...your update statements go here...]
COMMIT;
```

**Edit:** About security, because I have seen it in one of your comments. If a parameter is user supplied, you want to escape your inputs with `mysql_real_escape_string()`:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE url = ('".mysql_real_escape_string($your_url)."'");
```

For details about security, please read [the PHP manual about mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) and/or [google about SQL injection](http://www.google.com/search?q=sql+injection)