# Which is better way to manipulate data in DB?

Tags: php, mysql, database, data-retrieval

In MySQL there are also functions. For example `DAY()`, `ASCII()`, `DATEDIFF()`, and so on, a lot of function. So it is possible to make complicated queries using these functions. And all computing/manipulation with data will be done still in MySQL by MySQL functions. And I can get the result of my query in PHP already prepared by MySQL as refined as only possible.

But it’s also possible to compute/manipulate data from DB using PHP function. I mean, I retrieve data from DB using as simple SQL query as possible, then get it into an array, fetch that array into variables and only now, using PHP functions, begin necessary manipulations with my data to refine what I need.

So my question which way is better to work with DB? Should I use MySQL’s sever strength as full as only possible to get as ready-to-use data as only possible, or should I use more PHP functions to manipulate raw data from DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use MySQL (or other non-distributed databases) you might consider doing this in code. This will lighten the load on the database server while webservers are perfectly scalable these days. You only have 1 MySQL server, and can scale up to X webservers.

The best would be to create a helper class that wraps the database native functions.

If you leave the performance issues for what they are, it would always be better to use available functions instead of creating them yourself.

Comment: Ehrm. What gives you the idea that you can scale webservers, yet you can't scale database servers? Databases are perfectly scalable too, and doing calculations in the database is better performance-wise than doing them after retrieving all data.

Comment: MySQL is not a distributed database. You can read on multiple slaves, but you can't perform endless insert/updates/deletes on a single server. That is why performing these operations on your webservers has an advantage.

Comment: Still, functions in the database far outperform hauling all data to PHP and calculation from there. Just think about the implication of your answer when applied to the MySQL function SUM on 100.000 rows? The data transfer alone takes more time than calculating it in the database.

Comment: SUM should be done in a database, or if you have lots and lots of data in a Map/Reduce setup. 

However the initial question is speaking about date operations. These are relatively simple. 

Probably the best answer of this question is directly linked to the EXACT purpose.

My answer was there to point out the option to do things on the webservers to lighten the load on the database servers.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you'd be executing the same statements against the database in either case, it will **always** be faster to run your statements directly in MySQL (e.g. functions, stored procedures) than it will be to use any of PHP's MySQL extensions.

Answer (score -2):

look  ta my question [Text proccessing via Mysql Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158140/text-proccessing-via-mysql-query).
its better to store simple data into data base as each data one row.then get it to php and proccess them.

Comment: Not it's not... and the answer there says not to get PHP to do the searching.

Comment: check my question , others tell me the best way is storing data on db and process theme in php

Comment: @bizzare There is ***never*** a case in which running a query from PHP will yield better performance than running a query within MySQL itself. This is not opinion, it's just fact. You can debate whether it's more advantageous to run a query from PHP in a certain context, but that was not OP's question.

Comment: ok , thanks in my condition i must store simple data in db , again thanks for attention.

Comment: @bizzare: No, the people in your question said _the opposite_. Also please take more care over your posts; you have all the time in the world to avoid typos and missing capitalisation.